# Changing path for integration tests on a Paperclip Attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, rspec, paperclip

The documentation for Paperclip mentions that you can change the upload path for tests by placing the following code in the `test.rb` environment file:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = "#{Rails.root}/spec/test_files/:class/:id_partition/:style.:extension"
```

The issue I'm having is that the Attachment has a path set in the model, that doesn't get overwritten:

```
has_attached_file :photo, path: ':attachment/:id/:style.:extension'
```

When I'm running the tests the files get uploaded to the `/photo/` folder instead of `/spec/test_files/`.

I can probably achieve this by writing a custom Paperclip adapter, but there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is well past you needing help :) but on the off chance this helps someone else - you can use [paperclip interpolations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations) e.g.

```
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip.interpolates :path_prefix do |_attachment, _style|
  if Rails.env.test?
    Rails.root.join("spec/test_files/")
  else
    ""
  end
end
```

Then update your custom path to do use the prefix:

```
has_attached_file :photo, path: ':path_prefix:attachment/:id/:style.:extension'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, i couldn't create the folder, but instead of placing this:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = "#{Rails.root}/spec/test_files/:class/:id_partition/:style.:extension"
```

in the environments/test.rb as the instructions were saying, i added it in the rails_helper.rb

Hope it helps.